# Passing the values of a dictionary into a function

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries which looks like this:

```
s = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, {'d':3, 'e':4, 'f':5}]
```

and my function takes in to numbers:

```
foo(num1, num2, num3)
```

Besides storing the values as new variables, is there anything I can do to not have to create a new variable?

Here's what I've done so far:

```
t = [tuple(d.values()) for d in s]
[foo(x[0], x[1], x[2]) for x in t]
```

Comment: Anything you can do to do what? What is your question?

Comment: You can use splat operator (`fun(*iterable)`), which is an equivalent to `fun(iterable[0], iterable[1], iterable[2], ...)`.

Comment: If you're always going to be passing dictionaries into the function, then why not change the arguments it takes in to a dictionary of numbers instead of the numbers themselves?

Comment: The function foo is out of my control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is more succinct:

```
[foo(*d.values()) for d in s]
```

but unfortunately you can't be sure for the order of the arguments passed to. So you can sort the dictionaries values by key:

```
 [foo(*(d[k] for k in sorted(d.keys()))) for d in s]
```